# How to filter array with array condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

```
var students = ["Malcom", "Jayne"];
var persons = [
    {firstname : "Malcom", lastname: "Reynolds"},
    {firstname : "Kaylee", lastname: "Frye"},
    {firstname : "Jayne", lastname: "Cobb"}
];
```

I want to filter(or map, forEach whatever) persons array with students array.
Students array is dynamic, so its length can be changed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is it that you are trying to achieve? Do you want to return each person that is a student? And do you want to result to be in another new array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with `filter` along with `some`.

```js
var students = ["Malcom", "Jayne"];

var persons = [
    {firstname : "Malcom", lastname: "Reynolds"},
    {firstname : "Kaylee", lastname: "Frye"},
    {firstname : "Jayne", lastname: "Cobb"}
];

console.log(persons.filter(person => students.some(student => student == person.firstname)))

// An advice, maybe you want to put everything to lower case
// to prevent a wrong result because of case mismatch
// (e.g. "Malcom" !== "malcom"). 
// It would be:

persons.filter(person => students.some(student => student.toLowerCase() === person.firstname.toLowerCase()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
var students = ["Malcom", "Jayne"],
    persons = [{ firstname: "Malcom", lastname: "Reynolds" }, { firstname: "Kaylee", lastname: "Frye" }, { firstname: "Jayne", lastname: "Cobb" }],
    result = persons.filter(function (a) {
        return this.has(a.firstname);
    }, new Set(students));

console.log(result);
```

ES6

```js
var students = ["Malcom", "Jayne"],
    persons = [{ firstname: "Malcom", lastname: "Reynolds" }, { firstname: "Kaylee", lastname: "Frye" }, { firstname: "Jayne", lastname: "Cobb" }],
    result = persons.filter((set => a => set.has(a.firstname))(new Set(students)));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to filter the array by checking if their `firstname` is in the `students` array:

```
persons.filter(function(person) { return students.indexOf(person.firstname) >= 0 });
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use `filter()` and `includes()`

```js
var students = ["Malcom", "Jayne"];
var persons = [
    {firstname : "Malcom", lastname: "Reynolds"},
    {firstname : "Kaylee", lastname: "Frye"},
    {firstname : "Jayne", lastname: "Cobb"}
];

var r = persons.filter(function(o) {
  return students.includes(o.firstname);
});

console.log(r)
```

Comment: Is worth mentioning that Internet Explorer doesn't support `includes`

Answer (score 0):

```
var students = ["Malcom", "Jayne"];
var persons = [
    {firstname : "Malcom", lastname: "Reynolds"},
    {firstname : "Kaylee", lastname: "Frye"},
    {firstname : "Jayne", lastname: "Cobb"}
];
var filteredPersons = persons.filter(person => students.indexOf(person.firstname) > -1);
```