# Searching an Array inside of an Object with another Array

Tags: javascript

```
var movies = [{  
     title: "Mission Impossible 2",
     year: 2000,
     rating: 5,
     genre: ["Action"]
}, {
    title: "The Mummy",
    year: 1999,
    rating: 6,
    genre: ["Action", "Comedy"]
}]

var list = "Action"
console.log(movies.filter(function (movie) {
    return isInSet(list, movie);
}))

console.log(movies.filter(isInSet.bind(null, list)))

function isInSet(set, item) {
    return set.indexOf(item.genre) > -1;
}
```

This returns with mission impossible

Now what I would like to do is change list to

```
var list = ["Action", "Comedy"]
```

but when I do it returns with an empty array, Can anyone help explain how to search the array of genre with the array list; to return The Mummy?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Should it only return results containing all specified genres or atleast 1?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter array with array condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520430/how-to-filter-array-with-array-condition)

Comment: @ManuelOtto Should contain all specified genres

Comment: @fubar Not completely duplicated, I need a .bind function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you require every genre in the list to be included in the genres of a movie for a match, you can use a combination of the array `.filter`, `.every`, and `.includes` methods to get a list of matching items:

```js
var movies = [{  
     title: "Mission Impossible 2",
     year: 2000,
     rating: 5,
     genre: ["Action"]
}, {
    title: "The Mummy",
    year: 1999,
    rating: 6,
    genre: ["Action", "Comedy"]
}]

var list = ["Action", "Comedy"]

console.log(movies.filter(movie => list.every(item => movie.genre.includes(item))))
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this keeping the .bind? (for homework)

Comment: `movies.filter(movie => list.every(isInSet.bind(null, list)))` should work. Or do you need to get rid of all the arrow functions completely?

Comment: Would probably be better to get rid of them all together but if that's asking too much don't worry about it, thank you btw

Comment: Edit: I just tried using the .bind line and it seems to be giving me an empty array again

Answer (score 0):

Compare all the items in the search criteria against the `genre` of each movie, and return `true` if all were found.

This can be done with `.every()`.

```js
var movies = [{  
     title: "Mission Impossible 2",
     year: 2000,
     rating: 5,
     genre: ["Action"]
}, {
    title: "The Mummy",
    year: 1999,
    rating: 6,
    genre: ["Action", "Comedy"]
}];

var data = ["Action", "Comedy"];

var result = movies.filter(m =>
    data.every(s => m.genre.includes(s))
);

console.log(result)
```